# Configuring a Docker container and R to allow for API queries from inside the container?

Tags: r, docker, shiny, docker-compose

I currently have an R Shiny app running happily inside a Docker container, but any attempt by the app or any other instance of R to query an API times out. Any R instance inside the container can reach the outside world (e.g., download new packages via HTTPS) but not complete the API call using HTTPS. I've confirmed that the query works like a charm outside of a container using HTTPS both with and without specifying port 443 in the query. In an unsuccessful attempt to solve the issue, I also now have port 443 exposed in both the Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml.

Is there a trick to allowing R to make API calls from within a Docker container that I'm missing?

Example query attempt:

```
# Full query results for geoindicators based on ecosite
results_full <- httr::GET("https://api.landscapedatacommons.org:443/api/geoindicators?EcologicalSiteId=R036XB006NM")
# Grab only the data portion
results_raw <- results_full[["content"]]
# Convert from raw to character
results_character <- rawToChar(results_raw)
# Convert from character to data frame
results <- jsonlite::fromJSON(results_character)
```

docker-compose.yml contents:

```
version: "3"
    services:
        app:
            build: .
            ports:
                - 3838:3838
                - 443
            volumes:
                - ./:/srv/benchmark-histograms
```

Dockerfile contents:

```
FROM rocker/shiny:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    sudo \
    pandoc \
    pandoc-citeproc \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libxt-dev \
    libssl-dev \
    libssh2-1-dev 

RUN R -e "install.packages('httr', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('jsonlite', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"

EXPOSE 3838
EXPOSE 443

CMD ["R", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/benchmark-histograms', host = '0.0.0.0', port = 3838)"]
```

Comment: Are you at work? Do you have to specify a proxy maybe?

Comment: I wish it were that easy! I haven't been on a VPN or anything and don't need to specify a proxy when running the exact same code outside a container. It's just something about the container, near as I can figure.